# quadratic formula solver written in js not working

Tags: javascript

This quadratic formula calculator that I made is not working. It keeps returning the wrong values for some reason. I do not know why, the logic and code of the js math functions are alright. please help me fix this.

```
function calc(){
  var a = parseInt(document.querySelector("#a").value);
  var b = parseInt(document.querySelector("#b").value);
  var c = parseInt(document.querySelector("#c").value);

  root = Math.sqrt(b*b - (4 * a * c));

  result1 = (-b + root) / 2 * a;
  result2 = (-b - root) / 2 * a;
  if(root * root > 0){
    console.log(result1);
    console.log(result2);
    document.querySelector('#result1').innerHTML = "x = "+result1;
    document.querySelector('#result2').innerHTML = "x = "+result2;
  } else {
    result1 = "No Solution";
    document.querySelector('#result1').innerHTML = result1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is

```
(-b + root) / 2 * a;
```

`(-b + root)` will be divided by `2`, then multiplied by `a`. Enclose `(2 * a)` in parentheses in order to divide by `2a`.

Another problem is

```
if(root * root > 0){
  // display solution
// else display "No Solution"
```

What if the equation is `x^2+2x+1=0`? Then the root is 0, but there *is* a solution, namely x = -1. Change to

```
if(root * root >= 0){
```

Also, try not to implicitly assign to global variables - put `var` in front of your variables when creating new ones.

```js
function calc() {
  var a = parseInt(document.querySelector("#a").value);
  var b = parseInt(document.querySelector("#b").value);
  var c = parseInt(document.querySelector("#c").value);
  var root = Math.sqrt(b * b - (4 * a * c));

  var result1 = (-b + root) / (2 * a);
  var result2 = (-b - root) / (2 * a);
  if (root * root > 0) {
    console.log(result1);
    console.log(result2);
    document.querySelector('#result1').innerHTML = "x = " + result1;
    document.querySelector('#result2').innerHTML = "x = " + result2;
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#result1').innerHTML = "No Solution";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="a"><input id="b"><input id="c">
<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
<button onclick="calc()">calc</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much